# Carousel not showing proper image

Tags: javascript, reactjs, bootstrap-4

In a react project, I am trying to use carousel and but facing an image issue. In my project, default.js is the component within src/common folder where I am trying to implement the carousel.

Inside the img tag if the src is given as below, carousel shows proper image.

```html
<img className="d-block w-100" src="./slide2.jpg" alt="Slide 2" width="800" height="600"/>
```

However in the img tag if the src is given as below, carousel do not show proper image.

```html
<img className="d-block w-100" src="./../img/slide2.jpg" alt="Slide 2" width="800" height="600"/>
```

Just to mention all the images slide1.jpg, slide2.jpg and slide3.jpg are present in both common and img folder.

My guess is path mentioned in the src tag is not correct. However I am not able to find my mistake.
Below is the image of my folder structure. Thanks in advance.

[image: Folder Structure of the project]

Comment: Could you add how your file structure looks like?

Comment: I have already given the image of the Folder structure of the project in my post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do that, you need to wrap your src in a {} like that :

`<img src={"./../img/slide2.jpg"} />`

But the best way to do that (I think) is to import that file :
`import image from './../img/slide2.jpg';`

Then change your img tag to :

`<img className="d-block w-100" src={image} alt="Slide 2" width="800" height="600"/>`

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the `src` property to `src="../img/slide2.jpg"`.
This means 'up' one level from the current directory.